# WebAssembly include OpenCV

Tags: javascript, c++, opencv, emscripten, webassembly

I have C++ code that manipulates images with OpenCV and I'd like to compile it with `emscripten`. But `emscripten` doesn't find OpenCV if i type:

```
em++ test.c -s WASM=1 -O3 -o test.js -lopencv_highgu
```

The warning i get:

```
WARNING:root:emcc: cannot find library "opencv_highgui"
```

I guess `emscripten` doesn't use my normal include path. So the question is how can i compile my C++/OpenCV program to WebAssembly

Comment: Your development environment is malconfigured. What are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd first have to compile the entire OpenCV library to WebAssembly and then include it in your project. Here is some additional information: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/09/bootcamps-webassembly-and-computer-vision/

Comment: thank you. would sb guide me how to then include opencv wasm file inorder to compile my c++ code to wasm and js